# NLP Classificação de texto usando Python

Tags: python, machine-learning

Acho que meu problema é de classificação de texto, onde eu recebo uma string como entrada, então eu preciso combinar essa string com a escolha certa. Eu preciso de uma acurácia maior que 98,3%. Que tipo de algoritmo eu preciso estudar para resolver esse problema apresentado? Eu dei uma olhada no Bag of Words e no Word embedding mas eu não estou certo se eles resolvem o problema

```
Exemplo 1:
    Entrada: 
    onix 1.4 mpfi ltz 8v
    
    Possíveis combinações:
    onix hatch ltz 1.4 8v flexpower 5p mec. (combinação correta)
    onix hatch lt 1.4 8v flexpower 5p mec.
    onix hatch effect 1.4 8v f.power 5p mec.
    onix hatch activ 1.4 8v flex 5p mec.

Exemplo 2:
    Entrada: 
    gol 1.0 i 8v
    
    Possíveis combinações:
    gol city (trend)/titan 1.0 t. flex 8v 4p
    gol (novo) 1.0 mi total flex 8v 4p (combinação correta)

Exemplo 3:
    Entrada: 
    aircross 1.6 shine 16v
    
    Possíveis combinações:
    aircross shine 1.6 flex 16v 5p aut. (combinação correta)
    aircross live 1.6 flex 16v 5p aut.
    aircross feel 1.6 flex 16v 5p aut.
```

Estou tentando combinar nomes de modelos de carros de um site com nomes de modelos de carros de outro site.

Comment: Lendo a pergunta é só uma busca léxica, pois entendi o problema assim : Há um arquivo de texto que descreve modelos de veículos por seus atributos, separados por espaço, sendo um modelo de veículo em cada linha, o usuário digitaria um texto de pesquisa e a engine de pesquisa deve encontrar a linha ou linhas cujo a distancia de edição seja mais próximo do texto a ser pesquisado. Se for esse o problema e se apresentar uma amostra de dados faço um exemplo.

Comment: O algorítmo Naive Bayes deve te atender

Answer (score 1):

Você pode trabalhar com uma biblioteca que faça um fuzzy de string.
Fuzzy de string serve para achar similaridades nas strings mesmo se houver algum erro de digitação. Fuzzywuzzy trabalha com a distancia de Levenshtein para calcular as diferenças entre as sequências.

instalando os pacotes necessários

```
!pip install python-Levenshtein
!pip install fuzzywuzzy
```

importando as libs

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process
```

**Exemplo 1**

```
opcoes = ["onix hatch ltz 1.4 8v flexpower 5p mec.", 
          "onix hatch lt 1.4 8v flexpower 5p mec.", 
          "onix hatch effect 1.4 8v f.power 5p mec.", 
          "onix hatch activ 1.4 8v flex 5p mec."]


process.extractOne("onix 1.4 mpfi ltz 8v", opcoes, scorer = fuzz.token_sort_ratio)
```

Saída

```
('onix hatch ltz 1.4 8v flexpower 5p mec.', 59)
```

**Exemplo 2**

```
opcoes = ["gol city (trend)/titan 1.0 t. flex 8v 4p", 
          "gol (novo) 1.0 mi total flex 8v 4p"]

process.extractOne("gol 1.0 i 8v", opcoes,  scorer = fuzz.token_sort_ratio)
```

Saída

```
('gol (novo) 1.0 mi total flex 8v 4p', 55)
```

**Exemplo 3**

```
opcoes = ["aircross shine 1.6 flex 16v 5p aut.", 
          "aircross live 1.6 flex 16v 5p aut.",
          "aircross feel 1.6 flex 16v 5p aut."]

process.extractOne("aircross 1.6 shine 16v", opcoes ,scorer = fuzz.token_sort_ratio)
```

Saída

```
('aircross shine 1.6 flex 16v 5p aut.', 79)
```

Vale notar que no **exemplo 2** `gol 1.0 i 8v` a informação pode ser extraída para as duas strings, pois essa é uma ocorrência muito genérica.

Consulte a [lib](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/) para saber mais.

---

**Outra abordagem**

Utilizando o CountVectorizer e a similaridade do cosseno

**Exemplo 1**

Importando as libs

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
```

Definindo as opções, nesse caso aqui vamos comparar o primeiro elemento da lista com o restante. O token_pattern eu coloquei para ele inserir na tokenização também os números 1, 1.4 e etc.

```
opcoes = [
          "gol 1.0 i 8v",
          "gol city (trend)/titan 1.0 t. flex 8v 4p", 
          "gol (novo) 1.0 mi total flex 8v 4p"
]

count_vectorizer_gol = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=r'(?u)\b[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+')
count_matrix_gol = count_vectorizer_gol.fit_transform(opcoes)
```

Verificando o primeiro elemento contra os outros elementos

```
cosine_similarity(count_matrix_gol[0:1], count_matrix_gol[1:])
```

Saída

```
array([[0.5       , 0.53033009]])
```

Quanto maior este número, melhor. Neste caso o "gol (novo) 1.0 mi total flex 8v 4p" foi o que teve maior pontuação.

**Exemplo 2**

```
opcoes = [
          "aircross 1.6 shine 16v",
          "aircross shine 1.6 flex 16v 5p aut.", 
          "aircross live 1.6 flex 16v 5p aut.",
          "aircross feel 1.6 flex 16v 5p aut."
]

count_vectorizer_aircross = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=r'(?u)\b[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+')
count_matrix_aircross = count_vectorizer_aircross.fit_transform(opcoes)

cosine_similarity(count_matrix_aircross[0:1], count_matrix_aircross[1:])
```

Saída

```
array([[0.75592895, 0.56694671, 0.56694671]])
```

aircross shine 1.6 flex 16v 5p aut. obteve maior pontuação

**Exemplo 3**

```
opcoes = [
          "onix 1.4 mpfi ltz 8v",
          "onix hatch ltz 1.4 8v flexpower 5p mec.", 
          "onix hatch lt 1.4 8v flexpower 5p mec.", 
          "onix hatch effect 1.4 8v f.power 5p mec.", 
          "onix hatch activ 1.4 8v flex 5p mec.",
          "onix hatch ltz 1.2 8v flex 5p mec."
]

count_vectorizer_onix = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=r'(?u)\b[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+')
count_matrix_onix = count_vectorizer_onix.fit_transform(opcoes)

cosine_similarity(count_matrix_onix[0:1], count_matrix_onix[1:])
```

Saída

```
array([[0.63245553, 0.47434165, 0.47434165, 0.47434165, 0.47434165]])
```

onix hatch ltz 1.4 8v flexpower 5p mec. obteve maior pontuação